# Erro ao gerar quebra de linha via javascript

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

Preciso pegar o conteúdo armazenado na variavel produtos que puxa todos o conteudo da localStorage

e passar para um likn de whatsapp, onde o usuario vai clicar no icone do whats e enviar todo o conteúdo do localstorage.

segue o print:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

SEGUE COMO ELE ESTA PEGANDO[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para no link que envia a mensagem ao whatsapp ele vir reconhecendo o \n como quebra de linha, hoje ele mostra o \n como caracter como segue no print do whats
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

preciso que gere assim:

produtos:

produto 1

produtos 2

Ou seja com enter como quebra de lnha

Comment: Queira seguir as orientações dadas no quadro de fechamento da 1a vez que perguntou: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/553013/ - Você pode acessar o link e melhorar aquela pergunta. Para evitar duplicação de informações, travei o campo de comentários dessa aqui, queira utilizar o espaço apropriado da postagem original se precisar.